# Add different new values to an existing total

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have two cells in Excel (A1 and B1). A1 is supposed to be changed every month with different values depending on sales. and B1 has an existing value of $100.

For the month of August, the sale is $150 (which shall be entered in A1 cell). I want to add this $150 to the existing $100 in cell B1 to become $250 (which is very simple).

For the next month; however, I want to enter a different value in cell A1; say $200, and I want this $200 to be added to the $250 in cell B1 to become $450.

I don't want copy and past. In the same cell specified, I want to enter different vales while the value entered every time shall be added to the value in cell B1.

I wonder if I can do this in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do exactly what you want, as soon as you change cell A1 from 150 to 200, the old value of 150 no longer exists.

One possibility is that you keep **all** the monthly sales values in one column and use a formula in a different column to calculate the sum of all the values. For example, if you store 100, 150 and 200 in A1, A2 and A3 respectively, you can use the formula `=Sum(A:A)` to calculate the sum of all the values in column A. Note that this requires that you don't store anything else in column A, otherwise the formula should only include the cells that might contain monthly sales values, e.g. `=Sum(A1:A12)`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you wish to do using VBA Programming.
In your worksheet default named say Sheet1 you have say cell A1 that shall be overwritten every month and cell B1 is where you wish to see commulative total.

Right click on Sheet1 and click View Code. Alternatively press ALT + F11 and double click on the Sheet1 on left pane under VBA Project.

A blank VBA code window shall open. Enter the following code therein.

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("A1")

    If Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

    Else
       If IsNumeric(Range("A1").Value) Then
            Range("B1").Value = Range("B1").Value + Range("A1").Value
       Else

       End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Save and exit. Save the workbook as filename.xlsm. i.e. Macro enabled workbook. 
Now as you overwrite the value in cell A1 it shall get added to B1. Ensure that you update A1 only when intended else it shall just keep on adding it to B1. There's no such validation implemented in this code such that A1 should only get updated once a month! Just a basic check that A1 should be numeric to prevent run time error.

[image]

Additional reference https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/213612/how-to-run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel